# SwiftUI custom DatePicker date label format

Tags: swift, datepicker, swiftui

I am looking to change the format of the selected date in the label of this SwiftUI DatePicker:
[image: current SwiftUI datepicker]

Currently, it is formatted as `dd/m/yy` + time, but I need it formatted with the name of the month, as `dd MMMM yyyy` + time (e.g. 30 June 2020   9:00am).

This is how the default calendar app displays it, which is how I want it:
[image: default calendar app date picker]

I can't seem to find any methods within DatePicker to be able to do this.

Current code:

```
DatePicker("Starts", selection: self.$request.startDate.onChange({_ in ...}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I assume you want to use the DatePicker within a Form, I have to say that this is not possible. Because DatePicker doesn't give you access to the actual date Label.

If you use it outside a form you could reference to your date and format it with DateFormatter as you like it to be.